# A way to determine if "where like" matches 100% with a post in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to determine if this query:

```
$news_result = Post::with('image')
    ->has('image')
    ->with('tags')
    ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->get();
```

Has a 100% match with some title? If a user searches for "Some random news title" and in the database there is a post with such title to return some kind of marker?

Comment: 100% match would be: ->where('title', 'LIKE', $search)

Comment: Just change `where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')` to `where('title', $search)`

Comment: Just check the retrieved model e.g. `$post->title === $search`. If you need to do it DB side, use a `SQL CASE statement` to an an extra field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove '%' in your code

```
$news_result = Post::with('image')->has('image')->with('tags')->where('title', $search)->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `LIKE` operator is used to partially match something.

You should not use it, and do `->where('title', $search)` instead.